# Need some help with sharepoint web part development

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom web part where there is a text box. My custom web part also has a custom setting where user enters some values separated by commas. So on load, the UI should display the values entered in the setting (without commas though).

Is this possible with normal ascx user control, since it cannot access the sharepoint web part property at the time of creation and hence cannot display the message on load.

Need some help to solve this.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed you're probably doing something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649867.aspx).

What you'll need to do is pass your web part properties to your usercontrol. You can do this by creating public properties in your usercontrol class (demonstrated in the link I give above).

Code sample from the article:

```
// Loads a user control
MyUserControl myUserControl = (MyUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/_controltemplates/MyWebPart/MyUserControl.ascx");
myUserControl.Web = SPContext.Current.Web;
myUserControl.TextColor = this.TextColor;
```